# Converter to only run when textblock is updated

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

Converter

```
public object Convert(object values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (values != null)
    {
        string t = values.ToString();
        string date = t.Substring(0, t.IndexOf(" "));
        string time = DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm tt");
        return (date + " " + time);
    }

    return string.Empty;
}

public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

==================================================================================

XAML

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Start">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Start, Converter={StaticResource fixdate}}"  />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Start}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

how to only run my Converter when the texblock has been updated. the way it works now is once i select a date with the datepicker it populates the date/time in the textblock, but when i click save the Converter is being ran again which is changing the time. How can i get this Converter to only run when the textblock is updated. also i know the if test in the Converter needs to be changed i was just playing around with it to see if i can get it to work

Comment: there is a save button inside my app to save the data back to sql, but every time i click on it i it reruns the Converter

Comment: i was thinking that i need a if test to check if that data was modified, but i am not sure how to write that test inside the Converter because i dont know what to test for

Comment: see if the setter of the property Start is being called when you click save and propertychanged is fired for it?

Comment: that was the one of the first things i looked at and i did not see anything. Is there something else that i could try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Converter` is only run when the `Binding` thinks there is a new value to bind.
I'm guessing one of these situations occur when you click "Save":

1: Your code resets the item's `Start` property:

```
item.Start = updatedDate;
```

*) That is the same as @nit's suggestion, which you already checked.

2: In your collection of items, you replace the item that was just saved:

```
myList.Remove(oldItem);
myList.Add(updatedItem);
```

3: You replace the whole list of items that is bound to the `DataGrid`;

```
myGrid.ItemsSource = updatedList;
```

Answer (score 1):

As Sphinxxx wrote, the Converter is called when the Binding thinks that the value change.

One thing to do is to check your Save method, that there is nothing there that might cause that.

Another option is to set the UpdateSourceTrigger to Explicit, and then update the Binding after Choosing a new date in the DatePicker. I asume that if you do so, the problom won't occur.
Doint the explicit update is like that (an example of a Button with Binding for the IsEnable property) :

```
    BindingExpression be = MyButton.GetBindingExpression(Button.IsEnabledProperty);
    be.UpdateTarget();
```